# Long exact sequence into short exact sequences

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, exact-sequence

This question is the categorical version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101570/how-do-you-split-a-long-exact-sequence-into-short-exact-sequences) question about splitting up long exact sequences of modules into short exact sequence of modules.

I want to understand the general mechanism for abelian categories. Here's the decomposition I managed to get:
[image]

But it doesn't involve any cokernels like the module version does. The closest I get to a cokernel is via the following argument (which i'm not even sure is correct):
Since exactness is autodual, we have for any composition $g\circ f$ $$\mathrm{coim}g=\mathrm{coker}f\iff \mathrm{im}f=\mathrm{ker}g$$
This, along with the Image-Coimage isomorphism, yields the isomorphism of the *objects* $$\mathrm{Im}f\cong\mathrm{Coker}g$$
I'm not sure whether this is correct reasoning since it also leads to the isomorphism $\mathrm{Coker}g\cong\mathrm{Ker}g$ whenever $(f,g)$ is exact. So:

1. What is the general decomposition of a long exact sequence into
   short exact sequences in an abelian category?
2. Is the argument I gave for $\mathrm{Im}f\cong\mathrm{Coker}g$ correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, it finally *involves* cokernels (=coimages of the next arrows).

Your first line is correct: taking cokernel of both sides of $\def\im{{\rm im}\,} \im f=\ker g$, we'll get $\def\coker{{\rm coker}\,} \def\coim{{\rm coim}\,} \coker f=\coim g$. For the converse, take kernel of both sides.

Then, for the objects, your second line should read
$${\rm Im\,}g\cong {{\rm Coker}\,f}\,.$$
The statement ${\rm Coker\,}g\cong{\rm Ker\,}g$ does not follow.

And yes, this is the way how the long exact sequence splits into short exact sequences.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/nlVsMjB) is the updated decomposition. Can anything additional be said about the arrows? In particular, how should one intuitively interpret the coimage arrows?